# Universal covering of manifold is regular covering?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covering),  the regular cover is that its action is transitive on some fiber. From this definition, I feel the universal cover of manifold  (local homeomorphism to  Euclidean open sets) should be regular.  But I don't know how to prove it. Maybe, it is complex, if so, just tell me which book I should read is enough. Thanks.

> [image]

Comment: This is answered in the very bottom paragraph of the screenshot you posted. To prove this, you either have to know an explicit construction of a universal covering space or know some lifting criteria through covering maps.

Comment: Why do you want to know this specifically? What (else) do you know about covering spaces?

Comment: @ronno  When I read the proof of space form, seemly, the author assume the universal covering of manifold is regular.  So I want to know whether it is right.  I integrally read the Munkres' Topology  in some years ago.  I know the covering, fundamental group and classsification  of surface at that time. But now, I almost forgot all.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your screenshot, universal covers are indeed regular. This should be proved in any text that treats regular covers. For instance:

- In Munkres, this follows from the book's definition of regular cover, since the trivial group is always a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$.
- In Hatcher, this is part of Proposition 1.39, specifically of part (a), for the same reason as above. It is also implicitly used in the last sentence of this proposition.
- In Spanier, this follows from Corollary 3 in Chapter 2, Section 6, and is stated explicitly immediately afterwards.

To summarize, if your definition is in terms of deck groups, then this fact follows once you establish the lifting criterion for covering spaces. If your definition is in terms of the image of $\pi_1(E)$ in $\pi_1(X)$ being normal then it follows as soon as you know that the universal cover is simply connected, which is possibly by definition.